# Появление блока + плавный скроллинг к нему

Tags: javascript, блок

У меня есть ссылка, при нажатии - плавно открывается скрытый блок, но так как ссылка внизу страницы, то визуально не видно, что блок раскрылся. По этому хотелось бы, чтоб страница во время появления немного проскролилась к данному диву. (в js я практически ноль)

Мой код:

```js
function diplay_hide (clik) 
{ 
    if ($(clik).css('display') == 'none') 
        { 
            $(clik).animate({height: 'show'}, 500); 
        } 
    else 
        {   
            $(clik).animate({height: 'hide'}, 500); 
        } 
        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height:350px">HELLO!!!!!</div>
<a onclick="diplay_hide('#clik');return false;" class="podrobnee" id="podrobnee" href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> показать подробнее</a>


<div style="display:none;" id="clik">
  asdasdaasdasd<br/>asdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasd<br/>asdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasd<br/>asdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsada<br/>dsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdas<br/>dasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsa<br/>dadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadas<br/>dasdasda<br/>sdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdsdasdasdsadadsadasdasd
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function diplay_hide(clik) {
  if ($(clik).css('display') == 'none') {
    $(clik).animate({
      height: 'show'
    }, 500);
    $('body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(clik).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $(clik).animate({
      height: 'hide'
    }, 500);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height:350px">HELLO!!!!!</div>
<a onclick="diplay_hide('#clik');return false;" class="podrobnee" id="podrobnee" href="/#clik"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> показать подробнее</a>


<div style="display:none;" id="clik">
  asdasdaasdasd
  <br/>asdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasd
  <br/>asdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasd
  <br/>asdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsada
  <br/>dsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdas
  <br/>dasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsa
  <br/>dadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadas
  <br/>dasdasda
  <br/>sdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadadsadasdasdsdasdasdsadadsadasdasd
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все заработало! :-)